# How does sbt 0.13 choose the configuration scope to use?

Tags: scope, sbt, sbt-0.13

sbt "scopes" its tasks and settings. Documentation talks about the "scope axes" One of them is the "configuration axis" which seems to be magically selected for the evaluation of a task. Evaluate "compile" and the configuration scope is "Compile". Evaluate "test" and the configuration scope is "Test".

I cannot find anything in the documentation on how this selection is done. The most specific description on this topic I found was in [James Roper's "all that jazz" blog](https://jazzy.id.au/2015/03/03/sbt-task-engine.html). It says:

> When you don’t specify a scope, sbt will choose a default scope, in this case it has chosen the "compile" scope. The logic in how it makes that decision we won’t cover here.

Pretty terse, actually. So, my questions:

- Is there anywhere else a coverage on that specific "logic"?
- How does sbt choose the "configuration" scope it applies to the task/settings evaluation?
- Which "configuration" scope values exist? Is this a fixed list? Where do the existing configuration scope values come from? How (and why) to create new ones?
- Is there any "general idea" behind this whole scoping thing?

I feel that this is a key to understand sbt in general but I must admin that I currently have almost no clue on how sbt acts here and why it acts like this. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: this is a lot of questions all at once; it'd take a while to answer all of them. have you read http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Scopes.html ?

Comment: the specific mechanism by which sbt understands `compile` by itself to refer to `compile:compile` (the `compile` task in the `compile` scope) is called "delegation"; see the "Delegates" section at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Inspecting-Settings.html

Comment: Reading the "Inspect settings" page, I found: "[...] Otherwise, the first configuration defining the key is selected, where order is determined by the project definition’s configurations member." How can I see the "configurations member"? "inspect" or "show" did not show anything.

Comment: I'm guessing, but I suppose the answer is in the sbt source code.